# How can I Store this pointer in a buffer in C#?

Tags: c#, dllimport

```
[DllImport("Azoteq_HID_DLL.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet   =CharSet.Ansi)]
public static extern int SetCurrentSerial(int Size, void* Msg);
```

Here is my attempt, getting a syntax error "cannot convert byte[] to byte"

```
byte Size = new byte[1024];
void* Msg;
SetCurrentSerial(Size, &Msg);
```

Comment: your method expects an int rather then an array of bytes.

Comment: Shouldn't it be Size.length?

Comment: the method signature clearly says, the first parameter is of type int. Why you need to pass an array of byte to that?

Comment: That's why i came here to ask for help, i'm a novice and i'm tryong to connect with a dll in visual c#.

Answer (score 1):

We don't know what the method is doing; but if the `Msg` is the address *of the buffer*, then perhaps:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
fixed(byte* ptr = buffer)
{
    SetCurrentSerial(buffer.Length, ptr);
}
```

If the data is only local to the calling method, you could also use `stackalloc` to save allocating and pinning the array.

Comment: yes Msg is the address of the buffer, the dll is supposed to read an input and store it in a memory, than my task should be to read from that memory.